# Scipy - how to further optimize sparse matrix code for stochastic gradient descent

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, matrix-factorization

I'm working on implementing the stochastic gradient descent algorithm for recommender systems using sparse matrices with Scipy.

This is how a first basic implementation looks like:

```
    N = self.model.shape[0] #no of users
    M = self.model.shape[1] #no of items
    self.p = np.random.rand(N, K)
    self.q = np.random.rand(M, K)
    rows,cols = self.model.nonzero()        
    for step in xrange(steps):
        for u, i in zip(rows,cols):
            e=self.model-np.dot(self.p,self.q.T) #calculate error for gradient
            p_temp = learning_rate * ( e[u,i] * self.q[i,:] - regularization * self.p[u,:])
            self.q[i,:]+= learning_rate * ( e[u,i] * self.p[u,:] - regularization * self.q[i,:])
            self.p[u,:] += p_temp
```

Unfortunately, my code is still pretty slow, even for a small 4x5 ratings matrix. I was thinking that this is probably due to the sparse matrix for loop. I've tried expressing the q and p changes using fancy indexing but since I'm still pretty new at scipy and numpy, I couldn't figure a better way to do it.

Do you have any pointers on how i could avoid iterating over the rows and columns of the sparse matrix explicitly?

Comment: You might get ideas from this code review case: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32664/numpy-scipy-optimization.  It too involves iterating over the rows of a sparse matrix, calculating an error for each row, and moving on to the next.  The speed up includes streamlining the inner loop, finding the fastest iteration on the sparse matrix, and cython code.

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look at the scikit-learn SGD implementation (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/sgd.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I almost forgot everything about recommender systems, so I may be erroneously translated your code, but you reevaluate `self.model-np.dot(self.p,self.q.T)` inside each loop, while I am almost convinced it should be evaluated once per step.

Then it seems that you do matrix multiplication by hand, that probably can be speeded up with direct matrix mulitplication (numpy or scipy will do it faster than you by hand), something like that:

```
for step in xrange(steps):
    e = self.model - np.dot(self.p, self.q.T)
    p_temp = learning_rate * np.dot(e, self.q)
    self.q *= (1-regularization)
    self.q += learning_rate*(np.dot(e.T, self.p))
    self.p *= (1-regularization)
    self.p += p_temp
```

Comment: Ah, this is exactly what I was looking for. I'm going to follow your suggestion and see if I get the same results, with faster computational time.

Comment: No, your suggestion doesn't work. First of all, SGD says that e should be recalculated not once per step, nor once per rating, but actually once per factor. So I should actually iterate over all factors myself, my code it a bit incorrect as well. (I only iterate per rating). Can I somehow specify this update on each step with the : notation ?

Comment: @AnaTodor can you provide an algebraic equation for a step?

Comment: I don't have an algebraic equation for a whole step. But basically each step you have to go through each rating, recalculate the error for each rating and then readjust p and q based on error.

Comment: @AnaTodor any formalized algorithm description will do. I am pretty sure that grad descent might be exressed with matrix equation, I've done it several times a few years ago

Comment: You may be confusing it with Singular Value Decomposition, which it approximates. But I am not aware of any matrix equation for SGD... [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent)

Comment: @AnaTodor this is general wiki. I meant that for your case you have a costfunc expressed with matrices, so do it's derivative, which we evaluate on each step and increment with. By algorithm I meant steps definition in terms of users/items.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are implementing SGD? because in each step, you have to calculate the error of one single user-rating, not the error of the all rating matrix or maybe I can not understand this line of your code:

```
e=self.model-np.dot(self.p,self.q.T) #calculate error for gradient
```

And for the Scipy library, I am sure you will have a slow bottleneck if you want to access the elements of the sparse matrix directly. Instead of accessing elements of rating matrix from Scipy-sparse-matrix, you can bring the specific row and column into RAM in each step and then do your calculation.